# When is the distribution of a r.v. uniquely defined by its lower conditional expectations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I'm actually working on a harder problem but I'll start with the easier one.

Say we are given some domain $D$ on which a r.v. $x$ is defined. Moreover, suppose we know $E[x|x<T] \:\: \forall T \in D, $ and that this is a smooth function of T. Is it generally the case that you may invert to derive the p.d.f. of $x$?

The more complicated question I have is whether the same is true when you only know $E[x|x<T]+E[x|x>T] \:\: \forall T \in D, $ and want to invert the p.d.f.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ g(t) = E[X|X < t] = \frac {\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^t xf_X(x)dx} 
{\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^t f_X(x)dx }$$

Then

$$ \begin{align} g(t)\int_{-\infty}^t f_X(x)dx &= \int_{-\infty}^t xf_X(x)dx \\
g(t)f_X(t) + g'(t)\int_{-\infty}^t f_X(x)dx &= tf_X(t) \\
\int_{-\infty}^t f_X(x)dx &= \frac {(t - g(t))} {g'(t)}f_X(t) \\
f_X(t) &= \frac {g'(t)(1 - g'(t)) - (t - g(t))g''(t)} {g'(t)^2}f_X(t) + \frac {(t - g(t))} {g'(t)}f_X'(t)
\end{align}$$

So it reduce to a first order linear ODE. Not sure how to deal with the other version yet.